# Query join with a single table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

hi guys i have problem to product a query in SQL Server.
I have a table with this records

```
+-------+--------------+------+
|field 1|field 2       |field3|
+-------+--------------+------+
|B395   |B.U. 2013     |1002  |
+-------+--------------+------+
|B395   |LOCATION 2013 |      |
+-------+--------------+------+
|B395   |MATERIALI 2013|3304  |
+-------+--------------+------+
|B395   |REVENUES 2013 |2202  |
+-------+--------------+------+
|B396   |B.U. 2013     |1002  |
+-------+--------------+------+
|B396   |LOCATION 2013 |      |
+-------+--------------+------+
|B396   |MATERIALI 2013|3304  |
+-------+--------------+------+
|B396   |REVENUES 2013 |2202  |
+-------+--------------+------+
```

i would like a query that return like this

```
+------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+
|Field1|field2        |field3       |field4             |field5            |
+------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+
|B395  |B.U. 2013 1002|LOCATION 2013|MATERIALI 2013 3304|REVENUES 2013 2202|
+------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+
|B396  |B.U. 2013 1002|LOCATION 2013|MATERIALI 2013 3304|REVENUES 2013 2202|
+------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

i could do it with left join??

thanks a lot

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You've not made it particularly clear what you are trying to do however looking at your data I believe something like the following will work:

```
SELECT
    [field 1] = bu.[field 1]
    ,[field 2] = bu.[field 2] + ' ' + bu.[field 3]
    ,[field 3] = loc.[field 2]
    ,[field 4] = mat.[field 2] + ' ' + mat.[field 3]
    ,[field 5] = rev.[field 2] + ' ' + rev.[field 3]
FROM
    tableName bu
    LEFT JOIN tableName loc ON loc.[field 1] = bu.[field 1]
    LEFT JOIN tableName mat ON mat.[field 1] = bu.[field 1]
    LEFT JOIN tableName rev ON rev.[field 1] = bu.[field 1]
WHERE
    LEFT(bu.[field 1],4) = 'B.U.'
    AND LEFT(loc.[field 1],8) = 'LOCATION'
    AND LEFT(loc.[field 1],9) = 'MATERIALI'
    AND LEFT(loc.[field 1],8) = 'REVENUES'
```

I am assuming that the fields in the resulting table are composites of `Field 2` and `Field 3`, changing the `LEFT JOIN`'s to be `INNER JOIN`'s would mean that all columns are required. The above also requires the `B.U.` entry to be there before populating, but again you could change the joining where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use your query with my database field name but the result is 0 record,but without the
where conditions i have this result:

> ```
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013   REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304 REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  B.U. 2013 1002
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  LOCATION 2013 
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  MATERIALI 2013 3304
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> B395  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202  REVENUES 2013 2202
> ```

query

```
SELECT
[field 1] = bu.[No_]
    ,[field 2] = bu.[Dimension Code] + ' ' + bu.[Dimension Value Code]
    ,[field 4] = mat.[Dimension Code] + ' ' + mat.[Dimension Value Code]
    ,[field 5] = rev.[Dimension Code] + ' ' + rev.[Dimension Value Code]
FROM
    dbo.[Zoom InProgress$Default Dimension] bu
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Zoom InProgress$Default Dimension] loc ON loc.[No_] = bu.[No_]
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Zoom InProgress$Default Dimension] mat ON mat.[No_] = bu.[No_]
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Zoom InProgress$Default Dimension] rev ON rev.[No_] = bu.[No_
```

]